# Creating NuGet package from .NET Framework 4.7.2 project

Tags: .net, nuget

I have created NuGet packages for .NET Standard class libraries, that is really easy with `dotnet.exe`. But it seems that `dotnet pack` doesn't work for plain old .csproj files targeting the full .NET Framework.

What is the preferred method to generate packages out of these kind of projects? With dotnet.exe? with nuget.exe? with msbuild?

I'm lost. It looks like package creation is a craft more like an automatic process! It's so confusing.

Comment: I'd personally try to convert the project to use an "SDK-style" project file (as per .NET Core) - that can still target .NET 4.7.2 and it's much simpler to work with.

Comment: The quick starts for NuGet seem to recommend using Visual Studio, but presumably you're wanting to automate the process?

Comment: @JonSkeet Is there a sample around? I've never targeted anything other that .NET Standards! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @SuperJMN: It's exactly the same file format - just use `<TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>`

Answer (score 3):

The preferred method to generate packages out of .Net Framework projects depends at least if the project is SDK-Style, or not.

- SDK-style we should use: [dotnet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools#dotnetexe-cli)
- ["For non-SDK-style projects, the methods and tools are also dependent on whether or not the project has been migrated to PackageReference"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format)

Here we can find more details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (in Powershell):

```
cd "pathToProject"
& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" -t:pack -p:"PackageOutputPath=myPackage;Authors=Me"
```

If you get weird build errors run `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /t:restore` first

I have this from [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Pro-Dev-ISV/msbuild-issue/td-p/633578)